# Screens appear sometimes moved to the right on iOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo, react-native-paper

Sometimes when i navigate to a screen, the screen appear moved to the right. This only happen on iOS.
I've tried removing the `KeyboardAviodingView`, `SaveAreaView` ( using the SafeAreaView provided by react navigation too), Views that wrap the entire App to check if any of those was causing the problem, but with no luck.

[image: example]

`package.json` dependencies:

```
{
    "@unimodules/core": "~5.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "expo": "^36.0.0",
    "expo-application": "^2.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "^8.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-localization": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-server-sdk": "^3.3.0",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "i18n-js": "^3.3.0",
    "i18next": "^19.3.2",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "lottie-react-native": "~2.6.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "nyc": "^14.1.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "16.9.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^3.26.4",
    "react-i18next": "^11.3.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-appearance": "~0.3.1",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.264.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-formik": "^1.7.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.5.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-parallax-scroll-view": "^0.21.3",
    "react-native-platform-touchable": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.4.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.6.0",
    "react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-shared-element": "~0.5.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.4",
    "react-native-svg": "9.13.3",
    "react-native-svg-uri": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-native-workers": "^0.3.1",
    "react-navigation": "4.1.1",
    "react-navigation-animated-switch": "^0.3.2",
    "react-navigation-collapsible": "^3.0.3",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.2.2",
    "react-navigation-fluid-transitions": "^0.3.2",
    "react-navigation-header-buttons": "^3.0.3",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "2.1.2",
    "react-navigation-shared-element": "^0.5.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "1.9.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "remove": "^0.1.5",
    "sentry-expo": "^2.0.1",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
}
```

EDIT: The error only happens when i show the keyboard in the screen B and then go back to the screen A

Comment: Hi! You should create a mcve (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - if you don't figure it out your own in the process of doing so it will give an example that others can help you with!

Comment: please add code for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading `react-navigation-stack` to `2.3.11` fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when:

1) I navigate to a screen -> this.props.navigation.navigate ('');

2) I put the application in the foreground;

3) go back -> navigation.goBack ();

4) I find the screen moved to the right.

Comment: 1) and 3), specifically not the 3 because i use navigation.pop()